# How to call another component when I click a button in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react project, In this project I have App.js in that I have one button. and I have another component that is Child.js. In Child.js I have one paragraph tag.

Now when I click a button in App.js then I have to show paragraph tag, that paragraph tag belongs to Child.js Component.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Child.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Child.css';

export default function Child() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Hi Mark</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a state to tell when to render the child component conditionally. Set `showChildComp` inititally to `false`, then on button click you can toggle the value of `showChildComp` by the handler function `onBtnClick`. See the below code to understand the idea.

Without much context of what you are doing, this is the only idea/advice I can give you.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [showChildComp, setShowChildComp] = useState(false)
  const onBtnClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setShowChildComp(prevState => !prevState)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={onBtnClick}>Click here</button>
      {showChildComp && <Child /> }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```